# Highcharts solidgauge arc shape with 5 diffrent solid color (no gradiant)

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, gauge

I have used a solid-gauge high chart arc shape in Y-axis stops I want to use 5 different colors like

```
0 to 39 - #B31700
40 to 64 - #F22808 
65 to 79 - #F98928 
80 to 89 - #F3C50B 
90 to 100 - #27aae1
```

Problem is when giving the data like 90 the color is so much invisible of given color when the value is increase above to 95 or 97 or 100 then the actual color comes in chart.

Please help me out how can I get the proper color in the starting of a stops in y axis.

Here is my example with fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9jsp08v7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have found a solution.

Here is the fiddle link:

```
stops: [
    [39 / 100, '#B31700'],
    [40 / 100, '#F22808'],
    [64 / 100, '#F22808'],
    [65/100, '#F98928'],
    [79/100, '#F98928'],
    [80/100, '#F3C50B'],
    [89/100, '#F3C50B'],
    [90/100, '#27aae1'],
    [100/100, '#27aae1']
  ]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/avdq5rf6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the `dataClasses` feature instead of `stops`.

```
yAxis: [{
  ...,
  dataClasses: [{
    from: 0,
    to: 39,
    color: '#B31700'
  }, {
    from: 39,
    to: 64,
    color: '#F22808'
  }, {
    from: 64,
    to: 79,
    color: '#F98928'
  }, {
    from: 79,
    to: 89,
    color: '#F3C50B'
  }, {
    from: 89,
    to: 100,
    color: '#27aae1'
  }]
}],
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/vxgda85y/

Comment: @ Sebastian Wędzel Thank you for your help. I your fiddle `#27aae1` this color should start from 90 but start from 80. thanks again.

Comment: @SaifurRahman Nope, it shouldn't. `Dataclasses` defines colors for particular points. The last point has a value 90, so it fits the last range.

Comment: Please look at the #27aae1 color dial position it's starting point is not right whwn the value is 90. I have found a solution, if you want you can take look on that. thanks your co-operation.

Comment: Yeah, I think that your solution fits better to your requirements. Thank you for sharing it!